# Is this（apostrophe plus is）a contraction? What is the original form?

Tags: grammaticality, contraction-vs-full-form

What is the uncontracted equivalent of ' is (apostrophe plus is) in the sentence, “Aye, when he comes into 'is money, like” in the following?  If it is “it is,” what does “it” refer to?  Does “it” refer to “flush”?  If so, “flush” is used as an adjective, meaning rich, I think. I’m afraid it is not logical.
I would also like to ask the meaning of the last sentence below, "When he comes into 'is money, like."

> "How do you know him, Jimmy--- can I call you Jimmy?" asked Gemma, finding the friendship more and more unlikely. 
>   "I play in a band, see?" Dawson grinned, showing teeth already beginning to yellow with nicotine, and played a little air-guitar riff. "And he sets up for us at some of the clubs."  "So you're not really close mates?"
>   "Nah. He's just around, you know? Has a way of weaselin' out of things, our Roger, always talking about what 'e's going to do when he's flush."
>   "Flush?" repeated Gemma.
>   "Aye." Jimmy Dawson ground out the stub of his cigarette in the metal ashtray on the desk, and the metallic smell stung Gemma's nose. **"When he comes into 'is money, like."**

(Taken from the mystery novel: *All Shall Be Well* by Deborah Crombie) 
(Jimmy Dawson: wearing his hair in a pony-tail, working at the petro station)
(Gemma: Gemma James, a female sergeant, in London)

Comment: "... The marking of the omission of one or more letters (as in the contraction of do not to *don't*). ... *it's*, *I'll*, *gov't*, *fo’c’s’le*, * bo’s’n’s*" (Wikipedia) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe

Answer (score 2):

This is what's called a **spelled pronunciation**:  the speaker, who sounds like a stereotypical **cockney** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockney), "drops" certain letters, and when the writer writes their speech, they omit the letters too, so as to mimic the style of speaking.  The apostrophe is added to indicate to the reader that this has been done deliberately.

In this example, *'is* is *his*, *e's*, is *he's*, *weaselin'* is *weaseling*, etc.

Dropped "h"'s at the start of words, and dropped "g"'s at the end, are characteristic features of this accent.

BTW - the phrase "to come into money" is a figure of speech, meaning to suddenly receive a large sum of money, often inherited when a family member dies.  In this text, it sounds like Roger is expecting this to happen, so maybe an elderly (and wealthy) relative of Roger's is seriously ill.  "Flush" means "having a lot of money".

Answer (score 2):

**Flush** means 'well supplied with money' 
**'is** is **his** : dropping the initial 'h' of words is a characteristic of certain British accents and often used by writers to indicate that characters are not refined.

Answer (score 1):

'is is a contraction of "his". With some accents the "h" will be dripped. Like weaselin' is a contraction of "weaselling" (my spelling checker insists on a double ll).